# MessageService for current window in Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, catel

I'm trying to create a Message in my WPF application using Catel. I have a problem, because I'm trying to show this message over additional window (not over mainWindow)

I'm using Catel with Orchestra.MahApps.

When I'm trying to execute code like this:

```
IMessageService messageService = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMessageService>();
messageService.ShowInformation(message, title);
```

in my Additional Window ViewModel, it shows my message, but over my MainWindow. Is there a way to show it over my second window?

Right now I have a workaround with Events, but with my application growing, it will be hard to maintain everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Create (or override) a custom version of the PleaseWaitService. When showing the busy indicator, check the current foreground window and show that one.
2. If you really want per/view busy indicator, it might be easier to create boolean values on your vm (IsBusy) and bind to that from within the view.